# Create java classes from an xml schema

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl

The point is to make a simple white-pages web service which adds a person to a phone book (called addPerson() ) using SOAP. If there is already a person with the same first- and last name in the phone
book, a fault message should be returned.

I made the following wsdl file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="whitepages" targetNamespace="http://whitepages.ws"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://whitepages.ws" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://whitepages.ws" xmlns:tns="http://whitepages.ws">
            <xsd:complexType name="personType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="address" type="tns:addressType"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="firstName" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="lastName" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="phone" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="addressType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="street">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence/>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="postcode">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence/>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="city">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence/>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:element name="person" type="tns:personType"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="response" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:complexType name="faultType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="errorMessage" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="person" type="tns:personType"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:element name="fault" type="tns:faultType"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="whitepagesOperationRequest">
        <part name="person" element="tns:person"/>
    </message>
    <message name="whitepagesOperationResponse">
        <part name="response" element="tns:response"/>
    </message>
    <message name="WPFault">
        <part name="errorMessage" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="person" element="tns:person"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="whitepages">
        <operation name="addPerson">
            <input name="input1" message="tns:whitepagesOperationRequest"/>
            <output name="output1" message="tns:whitepagesOperationResponse"/>
            <fault name="fault1" message="tns:WPFault"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="whitepagesBinding" type="tns:whitepages">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="addPerson">
            <soap:operation style="document"/>
            <input name="input1">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="output1">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="fault1">
                <soap:fault name="fault1" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="whitepagesService">
        <port name="whitepagesBindingPort" binding="tns:whitepagesBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:${HttpDefaultPort}/service"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

I validated the xml and now I need to make the java classes(for both) for that schema but I don't know how to proceed...Any advice or tip would be really appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Comment: best point to start would be to have a look at the JAXB specification (or the reference implementation https://jaxb.java.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eclipse distribution that I am using has a wizard for creating JAXB class from schema:

- File -> New -> Other -> Create JaxB classes from schema.
- You will have to provide the target package for the generated output
- You might need to provide a binding file if you need any customization
- This is the detailed info on the eclipse distribution:

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Juno Service Release 1
>      Build id: 20120920-0800>
>
> (c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2005, 2012.  All rights reserved.
>      Visit http://www.eclipse.org/webtools

Another option is to use the [XJC](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html) compiler to generate the classes from the schema. it is included in the standard JDK.

In any case, you will have to extract the schema definitions to a XSD file and reference it from your WSDL:

```
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <import namespace="http://whitepages.ws" schemaLocation="NAME_OF_Your_XSD_FILE.xsd" />             
    </schema>
```